# Alternative to _errorURL response for matching Email in form - DE Manager

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I'm using DE Manager to create a DE when the user enters their email on the site. Essentially a web collect. I'm matching the email with the emails already established in the DE, and a repeat returns the _errorURL. 
I'm looking into an alternative to the _errorURL field that redirects to a URL, and instead does something on the DOM. When using the DE Manager, it doesn't seem like either the _successURL or _errorURL hidden fields can be removed. Can you had a javascript function that runs in the POST returns an error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

DEManager does not produce error codes as listed in the [Web Collect documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/). The only work around for error checking is to include some front-end Javascript checking.

There is an [idea floating around in Trailblazer](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TtazQAC) to include error codes.